# Ext JS: Assign a variable to data from store

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I want to change the value in one of my views of my project depending on the user's url. 
Currently, I have a store class that loads in the url dynamically using the loadStore method.

```
Ext.define('store.app.appStore', {
extend : 'store.Store'
, model : 'model.app.appModel'  
, alias : 'widget.app-appstore'
, proxy : {
            type : 'rest'
            , url : ''
            , reader : {
                type : 'json'
            }
        }
, loadStore : function(id) {
            this.getProxy().url = app.getApplication().getAppUrl();
            console.log(this.getProxy().url);
            this.load({});
        }
});
```

And a controller that loads the url depending on the id, and on start up then updates my form with the data.

```
Ext.define('controller.app.appController', {
extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',

refs :  
        {ref : 'appView', selector : 'app-appview'}
        ],

        stores : ['app.appStore'],     

        init : function() {
            this.control({
                'app-appview' : {
                    selectionchange : this.onStartUp
                }
            });
        },

        onStartUp : function() {
                this.getStore('app.appStore').loadStore();

                this.getAppView().updateForm({PARAMETER});
            }
```

However, I'm having a problem in working out how to assign a variable to the data I am loading, so that in my updateForm() method I would replace {(PARAMETER)} with the data.

The model looks like this:

```
Ext.define('model.app.Summary', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Model',

fields : [
   'id', 'name', 'address', 'phone', 'optionOne', 'optionTwo'
],

getId : function() {
    return this.get('id');
},

getName : function() {
return this.get('name');
},

getAddress : function() {
return this.get('address');
},

getPhone : function() {
return this.get('phone');
},

getOptionOne : function() {
return this.get('optionOne');
},

getOptionTwo : function() {
return this.get('optionTwo');
},
```

});

Any suggestions?

Comment: could you explain this `data` thing a bit better? I'm not 100% clear what would you like to pass to your `updateForm()` method

Comment: so i'm loading an object which has 6 fields (a basic model). I want to pass in to the updateForm one of the fields.

Comment: how does your object look like? :)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to complete the updateForm within the [store load](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-load) event. For instance, add a listener to the load event within the [controller's init](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller)

```
init: function () {
        Ext.getStore('app.appStore').on('load', this.LoadFormData);
},
```

Then within the LoadFormData method you would have access to the loaded data within the store

```
LoadFormData: function (s) {
        var value = s.data.items[0].get('myFieldFromStore');
        //insert value where required here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right, you must have somewhere in your code something like this:

```
var myObject = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    model: 'model.app.Summary',
    data: [['someid','somename', 'someaddress', 'somephone', 'someoptionOne', 'someoptionTwo']]
});
```

Where you create your object from the data you want to store.

myObject is an `ArrayStore` in this example which means you can have several items stored in your objects, all with the defined fields.

Assuming you want to get the `name` property of the **first** item in `myObject`

```
myObject.data.items[0].data.name
```

I'm not sure about the `getWhatever()` methods in your model.